# iOS Modal View Controller PageCurl Animation not showing

Tags: ios, ios5, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a `ParentViewController` which is in a `UIScrollView` along with its `SiblingsViewControllers` like the tree below.

- `RootViewController`

  - `UIScrollView`

    - `HomeViewController`
    - `ParentViewController`

      - `FormNotesViewController` - *Modal view to be presented using PageCurl*
    - `FooViewController`
    - `BarViewController`

The ModalViewController is presented by `ParentViewController` upon IBAction with a function below.

```
- (IBAction)onNoteOpen:(id)sender {
FormNotesViewController *notesView = [[FormNotesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormNotesViewController" bundle:nil];

//OPTION #1
notesView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
notesView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:notesView animated:YES];


//OPTION #2    
//    [UIView beginAnimations:@"PartialPageCurlEffect" context:nil];
//    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
//    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
//    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
//                           forView:notesView.view cache:NO];
//    [self.view addSubview:notesView.view];
//    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I have tried both option #1 and #2. Though they both showed the `notesView`, the application fails to show the transition.

I can't figure out exactly why.

Could it be because of `UIScrollView`? Could it be that I missed something? Any advice to debug this?

Comment: Have you checked the frame property on your FormNotesViewControllers view? Maybe you have to wait until viewDidLoad has been called in your notes controller.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:

```
FormNotesViewController *notesView = [[FormNotesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormNotesViewController" bundle:nil];

notesView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

[self presentModalViewController:notesView animated:YES];
```

option 2:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:notesView.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:notesView.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I had to resolve this using a different structure of views. Apparently having a lot of views in the ``UIScrollView`` and calling the ``FormNotesViewController`` from one of the sub-view of ``UIScrollView`` was related to the problem I faced.

I used a different structure instead for views organization. 

I'm afriad I couldn't try out what you have offered as a solution since I am no longer on the project. Thanks anyway though.